# Corporate Marketing Cloud Licence

Tags: api, licenses

We have a Corporate Marketing Cloud Licence, which includes 6M API Call. Is every API call to a DE counted as 1 call? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

API calls represent specific operations that your client applications can invoke at runtime to perform tasks.

- Query data in your organization.
- Add, update, and delete data.
- Obtain metadata about your data.
- Run utilities to perform administration tasks.

Unfortunately there currently is no way of seeing usage of API calls anywhere in the Marketing Cloud Interface and only possible way is asking Account executive or support about limits of your org.

Comment: So each API call to  a DE is counted as one call?

Comment: As mentioned yes if you are making any DML operations